# What exactly does this subroutine do?

Tags: perl, coding-style

A piece of historical Perl code I have has the following function:

```
sub binds { join(",", ("?")x$_[0]) }
```

It is later called with `binds(4)` or the like.  From what I can tell it is joining `?`s and `,`s but I'm lost as to exactly how, nor do I understand the `x$_[0]` part.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This function takes an integer (let's say `n`) as its first argument and returns a string of `n` question marks separated by commas.  Here's how it breaks down:

```perl
sub binds {
  join(",", ("?") x $_[0]);
  #         │     │ └──── the first argument to the subroutine.
  #         │     └── the repetition operator (think multiply).
  #         └─── a list containing only the string literal "?".
}
binds(4) # => "?,?,?,?"
```

It's probably a utility function for a database interface to create the specified number of `?` place holders which will be later bound to some specific values as part of an SQL statement.

Comment: Parenthesis are also important here as they force a list context, so you're joining `('?','?','?',...)` rather than `'???...'`

Comment: @snoopy: yes, good point.  I've updated my answer to reflect that important detail.  thanks =)

Comment: One pedantic point. `("?")` is not an array containing the string literal "?", it is a list containing the string literal "?".

Comment: @davorg: yes, also a good point!  I've updated my answer again to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

Let's ask Perl's opinion on how to parse that.

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e'sub binds { join(",", ("?")x$_[0]) }'
sub binds {
    join ',', ('?') x $_[0];
}
-e syntax OK
```

With some whitespace added, the parts become clear.

- [`x`](http://p3rl.org/op#Multiplicative-Operators) is the repetition operator.
- `$_[0]` is the first subroutine argument, see [`@_`](http://p3rl.org/var#%40_).

Answer (score 1):

This code is generating a list of question marks separated by commas, likely to generate parameter bind points in a DBI application.

The $_[0] is the number of binds, binds(4) would return "?,?,?,?".